# assets-library convert base64

Tags: react-native, base64, assetslibrary

I want to convert base64 the picture to phone for save my db,
i select my app in local gallery , get my data, like =>

```
>     filename: "IMG_0005.JPG"
>     height: 2002
>     isStored: true
>     playableDuration: 0
>     uri: "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=ED7AC36B-...-B6D696F4F2ED&ext=JPG"
>     width: 3000
```

I want both ios and android to run as well, i try many library, most libraries support ios, did you know anything useful code to react-native library or another idea?

i found solution

--Edit--

```
import {
  Image,
  ImageStore,
  ImageEditor,
} from 'react-native';

Image.getSize(image.uri, (width, height) => {
  let imageSettings = {
    offset: { x: 0, y: 0 },
    size: { width: width, height: height }
  };
  ImageEditor.cropImage(image.uri, imageSettings, (uri) => {
    ImageStore.getBase64ForTag(uri, (data) => {
        console.log('base64 ==> ',data)
    }, e => console.warn("getBase64ForTag: ", e))
  }, e => console.warn("cropImage: ", e))
})
```

Comment: I could not get your question. I request you to elaborate it more better.

Comment: hi @Ron , i try convert base64 to data.uri for save my database